# Richtext not working when preview in webbrowser - lotusspellshecker not found

Tags: html, xpages, spell-checking, richtext, domino-designer-eclipse

I try to develop and test XPages locally as much as possible because of speed. One thing that have been bugging me for years now is that richtext fields does not work when using "Preview in webbrowser".

This is the XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"> 
    <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"></xp:inputRichText>

</xp:view>
```

The result in webbrowser is an empty screen

In developer tools it looks like this

[image]

I get the same result on two computers, I am using english version of designer, 9.0.1 FP8. It does not make a difference if lang="sv" or lang="en"

The HTML looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/css/@Da&amp;@Ib&amp;2Tfxsp.css&amp;2TfxspLTR.css&amp;2TfxspSF.css.css">
<script type="text/javascript">var dojoConfig = {locale: 'sv-se', parseOnLoad: true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.sv-se/@In.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspClientDojo")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspCKEditor")</script>
</head>
<body class="xspView tundra">
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/nn.nsf/Test.xsp" class="xspForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="view:_id1:inputRichText1_h" name="view:_id1:inputRichText1_h" type="hidden" value=""><input id="view:_id1:inputRichText1_mod" name="view:_id1:inputRichText1_mod" type="hidden" value=""><div class="domino-richtext xspInputFieldRichText"><textarea rows="1" cols="1" id="view:_id1:inputRichText1" name="view:_id1:inputRichText1" dojoType="ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspCKEditor"></textarea></div>
<input type="hidden" name="$$viewid" id="view:_id1__VUID" value="!eudik9rn2f!">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitid">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspexecid">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitvalue">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitscroll">
<input type="hidden" name="view:_id1" value="view:_id1"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">

XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
dijit.byId("view:_id1:inputRichText1").initForEdit();
function view__id1_inputRichText1_rteSubmit(thisEvent) {
 var rte=dijit.byId("view:_id1:inputRichText1");
 var txta=XSP.getElementById("view:_id1:inputRichText1_h");
 if(!rte || !txta) return;
 txta.value = rte.getValue();
 return true;

}
XSP.addQuerySubmitListener("view:_id1", view__id1_inputRichText1_rteSubmit, null, "view__id1_inputRichText1_rteSubmit");

}); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this so that the Richtext fields load correctly when preview in webbrowser

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1LO86299

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, there are some plugins not available for Designer Local Preview that are expected. ".ibmxspres" in the URL points to XPages-provided resources. Many of those since 8.5.2 were delivered via OSGi plugins. This is one of the reasons that over the last 18 months I've been working with IBM to get a developer license for the Domino server. That's available now from [developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/develop/collaboration/) and it's the easiest, quickest and best practice solution.